# Return a async list from SQL Server database and use in a datagrid WPF app

Tags: sql-server, wpf, mvvm, async-await, prism

I'm currently facing a pretty strange behaviour I'm uncertain whether I do something wrong or not but here is the problem.

I try to return a list asynchronously from a repository and load it into a datagrid in a WPF application using Prism. When I return the list synchronously, it loads just fine, but as soon as I use it async the program run, but the interface will not display and no error is triggered.

If you need more info don't hesitate - thanks in advance.

Here is the code - shortened for simplicity:

The view

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The view model:

```cs
public class ProductViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly IProductRepo _repo = new ProductRepo();

    public ObservableCollection<Data.Models.Product> Products { get; set; }
    
    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Data.Models.Product>(this._repo.GetAll().Result);
    }
}
```

The `DbContext`:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The `IProductRepo` interface:

```cs
public interface IProductRepo
{
    Task<List<Product>> GetAll();
}
```

The `ProductRepo` class that implements `IProductRepo` interface:

```cs
public class ProductRepo : IProductRepo
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ProductRepo()
    {
        this._context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public async Task<List<Product>> GetAll()
    {
        return await this._context.Products.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I tried to create an async private method inside the view model to load the data, then call the function in the constructor, but this doesn't work.

```
public void LoadData()
{
    List<Data.Models.Product> ProductFromDB = this._repo.GetAll().Result;

    foreach (var p in ProductFromDB)
    {
        Products.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: You must await every method that returns a Task: `await this._repo.GetAll()`. accessing Task.Result instead will potentially create a deadlock. Since constructors can't be async, you can't execute async code in their scope. If you can't. defer the creation of the collection and call the async code after type construction, you must use synchronous APIs. Keep in mind that you shouldn't. execute long running operations from a constructor. You should consider to change the flow and only partially read data or defer it completely. For example, the user could click a button to load data (async):

Answer (score 0):

If you really believe you need to load all data on initialization, then a simple solution would be to load the data from the view.

The point is that calling `Task.Result` on an asynchronous method will very likely cause a deadlock.
Additionally, a long-running constructor can interfere with or even break the initialization routine of the controls (UI).
Furthermore, not awaiting an `async` method will lead to undefined behavior as the caller's context continues to execute while the the `async` method is still running and pending to return.
For example, the caller can now leave the method scope prematurely and the `async` method can never return.

It's more than best practice to ensure that constructors return fast and are light weight. They shouldn't allocate expensive resources and should not start background threads, which is generally a surprise for the caller.
A constructor is not meant to execute any kind of operations except to initialize its instance members to a reasonable default. Even advanced instance configuration should take place outside the constructor.

Also be aware that `ToList` or `ToListAsync` will force the query to be evaluated client-side. This can hurt significantly the application performance especially when the table is big. On the other hand, the database is highly optimized to execute queries efficiently, which makes server-side query evaluation favorable.
Since you are only fetching the complete table, it doesn't really matter in your scenario. But in case of advanced queries it can make the difference.

The following example shows how to execute the asynchronous initialization from the view. Depending on the exact scenario other solution can be applied.
The example assumes that the `ProductViewModel` is created and exposed by the main view model class. But the caller doesn't matter. Just let the control that creates the instance call the long-running initialization routine:

**IInitializable.cs**
Introducing as dedicated interface even allows to anonymously call all `async` and long-running initialization routines on application composition, for example in a dependency injection context.
This generally works in any composition context, for example when using composition to manage the hierarchy of classes.
In case of this example, the composition root of all view models would be the main view model class.

```cs
public interface IInitializable
{
  Task<bool> InitializeAsync();
  bool IsInitialized { get; }
}
```

**ProductViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class ProductViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IInitializable
{
  private readonly IProductRepo _repo = new ProductRepo();

  public ObservableCollection<Data.Models.Product> Products { get; }
  public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }
    
  public ProductViewModel()
  {
    // Only initialize to a reasonable default. 
    // Expensive initialization is deferred.
    this.Products = new ObservableCollection<Data.Models.Product>();
  }

  // Allow to defer long-running initialization routines.
  // Such routines can be both, synchronous or asynchronous.
  public async Task<bool> InitializeAsync()
  {
    if (this.IsInitialized)
    {
      return;
    }

    // You should rename 'GetAll' to 'GetAllAsync'
    List<Product> allProducts = await this._repo.GetAll();
    allProducts.ForEach(this.Products.Add);   

    this.IsInitialized = true;
    return this.IsInitialized;
  }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IInitializable
{
  public ProductViewModel ProductViewModel { get; }
  public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }
  
  private IList<IInitializable> InitializableDependencies { get; }
    
  public MainWindowViewModel()
  {
    // The container for polymorphic and anonymous iteration
    this.InitializableDependencies = new List<IInitializable>();

    // Create the composition tree. 
    // Because expensive initialization of dependencies is deferred,
    // the type construction is cheap and guaranteed to return fast.
    this.ProductViewModel = new ProductViewModel();

    // Store potential IInitialize implementation for later initialization.
    // This allows to use polymorphism to improve the code.
    // Additionally, we avoid explicit knowledge whether the instantiated type implements this interface or not.
    // This enhances extensibility significantly.
    TryAddInitializable(this.ProductViewModel);
  }

  // Store IInitializable implementations anonymously for later iteration.
  private bool TryAddInitializable(object instance)
  {        
    if (instance is IInitializable initializableInstance)
    {    
      this.InitializableDependencies.Add(initializableInstance);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  // Allow to defer long-running initialization routines.
  // Such routines can be both, synchronous or asynchronous.
  public async Task<bool> InitializeAsync()
  {
    if (this.IsInitialized)
    {
      return;
    }

    // Cascade IInitializeAsync calls. In context of dependency injection
    // this wouldn't be necessary as the IoC container would allow to filter
    // all types that implement IInitializable to call InitializeAsync on each type explicitly.
    // Because we only need to know the IINitializable interface, the calls are anonymous, allowing easy extension of the code.
    foreach (IInitializable initializableInstance in this.InitializableDependencies)
    {
      // Trigger the cascade of InitializeAsync calls, 
      // given that the ProductViewModel is the composition root of other view model classes 
      // or classes that implement IInitializable.
      bool isSuccesfullyInitialized = await initializableInstance.InitializeAsync();
    }

    this.IsInitialized = true;
    return this.IsInitialized;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
The idea is to start the deferred initialization from the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event of a reasonable element (in this case this is the `MainWindow`).
If `ProductViewModel` is created by another view model class, then you would have to let this view model implement `IInitializable` too and cascade the `InitializeAsync` method calls.

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get; }
 
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.ViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.ViewModel;
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }
  
  // Use the Loaded event to execute long-running or resource intensive routines
  // outside the constructor.
  // Define handler as 'async void' to await the async method calls.
  private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.ViewModel is IInitializable initializableViewModel)
    {
      // Trigger the cascade of InitializeAsync calls, 
      // given that the MainWindowViewModel is the composition root of all view model classes 
      // or classes that implement IInitializable in general.
      _ = await initializableViewModel.InitializeAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <ProductView DataGridItemsSource="{Binding ProductViewModel.Products}" />
</Window>
```